# unable to use NotificationListenerService to cancel all notifications from widget

Tags: android

I am trying to build a widget that will clear all notifications yet I am unable to get an instance of the NotificationsListenerService.

I have a class named NLService that extends NotificationListenerService and I'm trying to call it from a class named ActionReceiver that extends BroadcastReceiver.

onNotificationRemoved and onNotificationPosted are working fine so the problem is not with the NotificationListenerService class itself.

This is the exception I get :

```
 java.lang.runtimeexception ... unable to start receiver ... java.lang.nullpointerexception
```

I'm initialising the object using these lines of code:

```
NLService nls = new NLService();
nls.cancelAllNotifications();
```

my manifest looks like this:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="MyWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.flashlight.ActionReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="COM_FLASHLIGHT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.flashlight.NLService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: yes. some time has passed. I think I used intents to solve the problem.
I can look for the code and post it if you are experiencing the same problem

Comment: Yes please, it would help very much if you dont mind.

Comment: @user1406716 - I posted the answer. it's a lot of code to post here 
I can send you a zip file of the project by email. contact me by private message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NotificationListenerService:
    package com.example.flashlight;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService implements ActionIFC {


     private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
     private NLServiceReceiver nrec ;

     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        nrec = new NLServiceReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.flashlight.LIST_NOTE");
        registerReceiver(nrec, filter);

    }


     @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
//       Log.d(TAG,"in");
//       Log.i(TAG,"**********  onNotificationPosted");
//       Log.i(TAG,"ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());
//       Intent i = new  Intent("com.example.newnote.NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_EXAMPLE");
//       i.putExtra("notification_event","onNotificationPosted :" + sbn.getPackageName() + "\n");
//       sendBroadcast(i);

    }

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {


//        i.putExtra("notification_event","onNotificationRemoved :" + sbn.getPackageName() + "\n");
//
//        sendBroadcast(i);     
    }

    public void killNotifications(){
        this.cancelAllNotifications();
    }


    class NLServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
//      public NLServiceReceiver(){}

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          Log.d("flash", "got to not listener");
            if(intent.getStringExtra("action").equals(CLEAR_NOTIFICATIONS)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "CLEARING NOTIFICATIONS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                NLService.this.cancelAllNotifications();
            }
        }

    }





}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements ActionIFC {
    onReceive{
        else if (action.equals(CLEAR_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
            Intent i7 = new Intent("com.example.flashlight.LIST_NOTE");
            i7.putExtra("action", CLEAR_NOTIFICATIONS);
            context.sendBroadcast(i7);
            }
        }
 }
```

AppWidgetProvider:

```
Intent receiverNotification =  new Intent(context,ActionReceiver.class);
receiverNotification.setAction("COM_FLASHLIGHT");
receiverNotification.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
receiverNotification.putExtra("action", CLEAR_NOTIFICATIONS);
PendingIntent pendingIntentNotification = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2,   receiverNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
receiverRotate.setData(Uri.parse(receiverRotate.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```